# Request returns bytes and I'm failing to decode them

Tags: python, json, byte, python-requests, decoding

Essentially I made a request to a website and got a byte response back: `b'[{"geonameId:"703448"}..........'.`  I'm confused because although it is of type byte, it is very human readable and appears like a list of json.  I do know that the response is encoded in latin1 from running `r.encoding` which returned `ISO-859-1` and I have tried to decode it, but it just returns an empty string.  Here's what I have so far:

```
r = response.content
string = r.decode("ISO-8859-1")
print (string)
```

and this is where it prints a blank line.
However when I run

```
len(string)
```

I get: back `31023`
How can I decode these bytes without getting back an empty string?

Comment: in python 2.x the b prefix will cause the enclosed string to become a type `str` you may have some encoded characters already hidden somewhere within. On Python 3.x you will receive a `bytes` literal. why do you believe you need to perform any encoding/decoding?

Comment: Because I need to parse the json, and I just tried looping over it: with `for i in range(len(contents)): print content[i]` and it's just printing out lots of numbers.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Did you try to parse it with the `json` module?

```
import json
parsed = json.loads(response.content)
```

Comment: Yes and I got: `JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'`

Comment: And when you do `json.loads(response.content.decode('latin1'))`?

Comment: There should be a header in the response object telling you what encoding it has. You should decode the content with that codec, otherwise any unusual characters (emoji, accents, some quote characters, ...) will end up garbled. See the Answer from @salah

Comment: @mzc Please add the `content.decode` comment directly to the answer.

Comment: @mzc, decode('latin1') doesn’t work always, in case of the content-type is `text/html; charset=UTF-8`, it fails.

Answer (score 31):

Another solution is to use response.text, which returns the content in unicode

```
Type:        property
String form: <property object at 0x7f76f8c79db8>
Docstring:  
Content of the response, in unicode.

If Response.encoding is None, encoding will be guessed using
``chardet``.

The encoding of the response content is determined based solely on HTTP
headers, following RFC 2616 to the letter. If you can take advantage of
non-HTTP knowledge to make a better guess at the encoding, you should
set ``r.encoding`` appropriately before accessing this property.
```

Comment: This is a much better idea than the accepted answer, as it will use the appropriate encoding.

Comment: Yes, this is what is suggested in the docs: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content

Answer (score 13):

There is `r.text` and `r.content`. The first one is a string, the second one is bytes.

You want

```
import json

data = json.loads(r.text)
```

Comment: I have a similar issue and when I use r.text, it's empty.

Comment: Then maybe the server does not return anything.

Comment: I'm requesting the source / HTML of a webpage (http://www.dockethound.com) and when I use r.content, it shows up.

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar issue using `beautifulsoup4` and `requests` while scraping webpages, however both `response.text` and `response.content` looked like it was bytes.

The response headers included `'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'` encoding in the headers, also had this in the response headers - `'Content-Encoding': 'br'`.  It turns out I hadn't installed `brotlipy` in the environment and running `pip install brotlipy` fixed my issues.  I thought `chardet` or `cchardet` would be enough, but the data needed to be correctly decompressed.

A similar issue was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49584929/unable-to-decode-python-web-request) in the same way, and linking to this answer since it didn't come up until I explicitly searched for brotli compression.

Comment: I had the same issue and installing brotlipy fixed the bytes response problem.

Comment: And there was no need to parse the response with the json module. Just response.text worked.