# Decoding bytes doesn't seem to decode

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, encoding, python-requests

While trying to get the html source of an... "academic" site I have trouble with decoding. I am using the requests commands:

```
resp = requests.get(url)
print(resp.content)
```

edit: I did try `resp.text`

The result is something like this:

```
"b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\".
```

Bytes. Cool. I tried using `.decode("format")` with various formats mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html) (`iso`, `latin`, `utf`, `cp`) but I had no luck.

Here is what some of those printed:

**utf-8:**

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

**latin-1:**

```
"ÿØÿàJFIFÿÛC         2! !222222222222222222222222Äµ}"
```

**iso8859_2:**

```
"˙Ř˙ŕJFIF˙ŰC         2!!2222222222"
```

---

edit 2: As per [this Q&A](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364/are-questions-about-adult-web-apps-on-or-off-topic/367#367) I cannot post the link, or refer to the webpage.

---

Even though this question is about decoding the source, it would also be great if you could point towards alternative solutions (i.e. for the others methods I tried; see below)

1) I tried using selenium but the following prevents it from getting the source: "Accessibility support is partially disabled due to compatibility issues with new Firefox features." (The problem seems to be an add-on that is required to login to the site)

Selenium code:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
htmlSource = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlSource,'lxml')
```

2) Using urllib didn't work either, and it threw an HTTPError 302 infinite loop. I tried using a cookiejar but to no avail.

Comment: Have you ever try the `utf-16`?

Comment: It returns: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: illegal UTF-16 surrogate

Comment: JFIF stands for JPEG File Interchange Format. You're trying to decode an image as text.

Comment: @IljaEverilä, thanks, that makes some sense since there is an image in the source code (<body><img>...</img></body>), but driver.page_source is supposed to get the html source, which I don't see how it translates to a JPEG file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/41068125/7432972:

`resp.text` should return Unicode text in your case.

Please do post back and let me know if this works or not as I've never had that problem personally before, possibly because I did always use `request_response.text` except for when feeding the response into `bs4`.

EDIT:

As per @Ilja_Everilä, you got an image as a response instead of the source you were looking for. I'd check what response code you receive for that request (`resp.status_code`), there's a chance it won't be 200, meaning the server returns some other message as a response. If that is the case, changing `user-agent` to something else may fix it, although it seems like the website in question doesn't want requests from the `requests` module, at the very least.

Or, even more likely, it has to do with that addon you mentioned that's needed for login. It's possible to add an addon to a `selenium.webdriver.FirefoxProfile()` through `.add_extension('/path/to/addon')`. Any sort of configuration for the addon, however, I could not help with.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention in the question that I did try .text too. Same result:����JFIF��C 2!!22

What about bs4 though? I do plan to use it later

Comment: @KostasMouratidis, as for `bs4`, it doesn't see `request_response.text` as valid HTML (unsurprisingly), so you just have to pass `request_response.content` to it instead, that's about all I know.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the problem; the response code is 200, and when I tried to avoid requests I used urllib (the rest of the code is in the original question) by setting these custom headers (which worked for various other sites):

`headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17"`

Comment: I added on another part just now, that's as far as my knowledge will get you, I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding the addon. I did find the path, and there are about 10 which are named something like: `p = "{f759ca51-3a91-4dd1-ae78-9db5eee9ebf0}.xpi"`. The issue isn't going through them 1 by 1, but that I can't even open one. I tried `add_extension(extension=p)` (and also tried using the whole path with `os.path.abspath`) but I get a unicode error (??). Being on windows 10 I then tried using double slashes (\\) for the path but that didn't work either. Any idea as to what might have caused this?

Comment: I've encountered a similar problem and ended up downloading a fresh copy of the needed add-on from addons.mozilla.org. That particular one was pre-configured out of the box, however. I'm not sure if it's the path that's the problem for you, you can check with os.path.exists('<drive letter>:\\path\\to\\addon'). You could also try renaming a copy of that xpi file to something more legible. I think the real problem may be that xpi file is not the whole addon, however and is just part of a configuration. I'll stop replying now as this has gone way past the original question.

Comment: I did use the os.path.exists and it was True. I re-installed the addon and got the WHOLE thing to work!! It returned the source beautifully (pun intended). Then, I encountered a problem when sending the keys for login (ConnectionRefusedError [...] target machine actively refused it) but that's another thing. Anyway, that did work, and it is a very interesting thing to know for future reference. Thanks for the help!