# unable to decode Python web request

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, brotli

I am trying to make web request to my trading account . Python is unable to decode the web request. Web request is successful with code - 200.

Here is the code below

```
import requests

headers = {
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36',
    'x-kite-version': '1.2.1',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'referer': 'https://kite.zerodha.com/orders',
    'authority': 'kite.zerodha.com',
    'cookie': '__cfduid=db8fb54c76c53442fb672dee32ed58aeb1521962031; _ga=GA1.2.1516103745.1522000590; _gid=GA1.2.581693731.1522462921; kfsession=CfawFIZq2T6SghlCd8FZegqFjNIKCYuO; public_token=7FyfBbbxhiRRUso3425TViK2VmVszMCK; user_id=XE4670',
    'x-csrftoken': '7FyfBbbxhiRRUso3425TViK2VmVszMCK',
}

response = requests.get('https://kite.zerodha.com/api/orders', headers=headers)


x=str(response.content.decode("utf-8") )
```

---

> b"1X\x14\x00 \xfe\xa7\x9b\xd3\xca\xbd9-\x12\x83\xbfULS1\x1d8\x9d\x0e\xd4\xcf\xbd\xb8\xd1\xbd4\xc0\x00\x13~\x94}\xe4\x81\xa4\x90P\x1cfs\xcd\x1e\xaeG\x9b},m\xbd\t\x84L1\xde\xa8e\x8a\xf1h\x0e\x0c)\x1a\x12\xfb\x06z\xec\x18\xe4r\xa1\x1c\x11\xe8 \xbcO\xec\xe2|\xa6\x90\xa9\xdf\xf2\xe1\xfa\xf3\x1e\x04\x0e\xa2\x8d\x0e\xc4\tw\xeb\xd9\xba\n\xf1H'l\xeb>\x08\x85L\r\x0cY\xf8\x81D;\x92!o\xfd\xbd\xe3u>3\x10\xe1\x8c;\xb8\x9e\xceA\xae\x0exX\xc9\x19s\xeb\xe5r~1\x98\xed0\xb8\xdc\xb4\x17:\x14\x96xAn\xb9\xf0\xce\xf2l\\xa6G?5O\x9b\xf3\xc1\\x1f\x0f\x8fs\x1b/\x17\x1a\x0c[ySAX\x1d'\xe7\xbb\nx\xacR~\xbb\x9f\xe0\x8c?s\xc0\x8f\xe0\x97\xff\xde'\xc7#\x8f\x97\xaf\xaa%\xf2\xf9\xfaC|\xcf\t\xf3\xeb\xaa\xdcs\xcc\xf5\xa3RM\xbaOY\xf5\x9fe\xfc\x07\xff\x01"

Unable to decode this. Tried unicode- utf 8 and various codes available on the stakoverflow but its failed.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

According to the `response.headers` (that you did not provide, but that are easily recoverable by running your code), the response is encoded using [Brotli compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brotli) (`Content-Encoding': 'br'`). You can decompress it with [brotlipy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/brotlipy):

```
import brotli
brotli.decompress(response.content)
#b'{"status":"success","data":[{"placed_by":"XE4670","order_id":"180331000000385",  
#"exchange_order_id":null,"parent_order_id":null,"status":"REJECTED",
#"status_message":"ADAPTER is down","order_timestamp":"2018-03-31 07:59:42", 
#"exchange_update_timestamp":null,...}
```

Now, it's JSON, as promised (`'Content-Type': 'application/json'`).

Comment: Sorry to dig up this post, but when I use `brotly.decompress(response.content)`, I have `brotli.brotli.Error: Decompression error: b'PADDING_2'`, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Use [brotli](https://github.com/google/brotli) instead of `brotlipy`. It is more frequently updated and maintained by google.

Comment: sorry, i have a question use brotli.decompress(response.content) raise error
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63809144/python3-8-brotli-brotli-error-brotlidecompress-failed

Comment: as mentioned in my answer on the above question, once brotli is installed, it is handled automatically by requests. You don't need to call decompresss manually

Answer (score 20):

If the server only returns `brotli` compressed response, response should be decompressed then it will be ready to use.

Fortunately, since [v2.26.0 update](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/community/updates/#id1), requests library supports Brotli compression if either the `brotli` or `brotlicffi` package is installed. So, if the response encoding is `br`, requests library will automatically handle it and decompress it.

First;

`pip install brotli`,

then;

```
import requests

r = requests.get('some_url')
r.json()
```

Answer (score 6):

I fixed this issue by changing the request header,

```py
headers = {
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    ...}
```

to

```py
headers = {
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, utf-8',
    ...}
```

Comment: This could work IF the API supports exporting directly as utf-8, can't be generalized as a solution imo

Comment: I agree, but its worth trying.