# python3.8 brotli brotli.error: BrotliDecompress failed？

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.8, brotli

mycode
python3.8

brotli=1.0.9

use request get url,headers use Accept-Encoding="br"
i need use decode br, because i think use accept-encoding=br more good

```
import brotli
import requests 
headers = {}
headers['Accept'] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
headers['Accept-Encoding'] = "gzip, deflate, br"
headers['Host'] = "book.douban.com"
headers['Referer'] = "book.douban.com"
headers['Sec-Fetch-Dest'] = "document"
headers['Sec-Fetch-Mode'] = "navigate"
headers['Upgrade-Insecure-Requests'] = "1"

s=requests.Session()
url="https://book.douban.com/tag/%E5%B0%8F%E8%AF%B4"
try:
    response = s.get(url, headers=headers)
except:
    return ""
if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.headers)
    if response.headers.get('Content-Encoding') == 'br':
        data = brotli.decompress(response.content)
        data1 = data.decode('utf-8')
        return data1
    else:
        return response.text
return ""
```

raise error

```
data = brotli.decompress(response.content)
brotli.error: BrotliDecompress failed
```

Comment: Same error, did you resolve it??

Comment: I ran into the same issue. I overcame it by requesting the data to be sent decompressed using `'accept-encoding': 'identity'`. Not ideal, but a workaround for now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is mentioned nowhere in the documentation of [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) but once [brotli](https://github.com/google/brotli) is installed, it is directly handled by Requests.

This means that response.content will be automatically decoded (similarly to gzip). You don't need to do `brotli.decompress(response.content)`

if brotli is not installed, you won't get any error message. Instead, response.content will stay encoded...

**edit**:

digging in Requests code, I found out that Requests use urllib3.response which implements usage of Brotli.

upon loading, urllib3.response will look for an import of Brotli:

```
try:
    import brotli
except ImportError:
    brotli = None
```

then when decoding a response, it will use appropriate decoder:

```
def _get_decoder(mode):
    if "," in mode:
        return MultiDecoder(mode)

    if mode == "gzip":
        return GzipDecoder()

    if brotli is not None and mode == "br":
        return BrotliDecoder()

    return DeflateDecoder()
```

thus if Brotli is installed, decoding will occur else nothing will happen and no warning to the user.

**edit2**
In fact, this is mentioned in https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content

Comment: Any insight into why this is the case? Your answer is the first confirmation of this phenomenon I was able to find.

Comment: I added some explanation in my answer

Comment: Thanks! I don't swing by here often, but your original answer completely saved my bacon and this is a helpful additional explanation. I regret that I have but a single upvote to give.

Comment: since i installed ```pip install brotli``` my response.text was readable, cheers mate!