# How to decode python byte code to ASCII? (Selenium. Getting xml from network response)

Tags: python, xml, selenium, ascii, bytecode

How to decode pyhon bytecode to ascii?
I extract data with selenium from network response. Should get xml.
Getting: ['b'\xa5\xff\xff\xc7\x88\xe4\xb4\xd7\x03\xa0\x11:|\xce\xdb\xb7\x0f\xf1\xdf\xfc\x1f\xdb\x93\x91^\xbc\xa3\xdd\xc2\x02V\x00\xba$\xbd\x10\xd2\xd0E\xf2\x90\xb6\xca\xee\x10\xbf\xbf_\xbf\xfc\xef?\xe9\x13{H\xf1\xa1\xa0\x00\x1c\x01(\x80\x1c\x81\x02(s\xe7Z\xf3\xb3N\xf5L\xdc>\xe7\x8f\xbbwl\xbf\x99\x91\xd4O\xde\xb4,\xf3PH\x02L1\x00\xc98\xc3,\x13!\x82\xc6\xc2\xa6Bd"k\xcb\x9d(\xb9\x13%WQr\x15%W\xb1\xe5J\t\x9e:\x8a\x03\x99\x06H\xd0\x8f\xd8\xfe\x9f9\xbc\xfc\x157\x111\xd7\x15\xaab\xfb\xe8;\xab\xee\xfc\x9b\xeeu\x10<d\x04\x06Y\xa8\xd7\x9f\x11...

Code:
...
    `for request in driver.requests: if request.response: text_file.write(str(request.response.body))`

I've tried:
`decoded = request.response.body.decode('ascii')`
or `request.response.body.decode('utf-8')` or cp1251/1252
I get:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Response should be xml (~1,5mb) in attached photo[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEIT3.png)

If I use:
`decoded = base64.b64decode(request.response.body)`

I'm getting smth like: b'T@\x00\xad\x9a\xb5\xba\xfa3u\xca\x84PG\xbd\x8a\xab\x1f\xcdcJ%\r\xd4\xff\x0c$)\x9a>.... not what to be expected.
Combining  decoded = base64.b64decode(request.response.body).decode('ascii') also doesnt help:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x85 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Help me, please.

Comment: ASCII is only in the range of 0-127, a `b'\xa5'` lies beyond that range, you have binary data there.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the Header 'Content-Encoding': 'br'
Installing brotly helped. Also deleting
[This message helped a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49584929/unable-to-decode-python-web-request)