# Python - Can't decode content when `br` is in `accept-encoding` header

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, http-headers, brotli

It appears that my script has started facing a decoding error during requests.
After some investigation and testing, I found out that the issue was related to the header `{"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br"}`. Removing the `br` solved the problem.

I even tested it on a simpler script and the same issue occured:

```py
import requests


URL = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/10"

response = requests.request("GET", URL, headers={"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"})
response_br = requests.request("GET", URL, headers={"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br"})

print(response.content.decode(response.encoding))
print(response_br.content.decode(response_br.encoding))
```

The first `print` works fine but the second one raises `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcd in position 1: invalid continuation byte`

So, to fix the issue, I have to force the `accept-encoding` without the `br` but I feel like it's more a workaround than a proper fix.
Are there more effective/elegant solutions to address this problem?

`Python 3.11`
`requests 2.31.0`

---

Thanks @mark-tolonen for the prompt comment

As stated in the linked [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69721272/17159275) and
in these `requests` [issue](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/4525) and [PR](https://github.com/psf/requests/pull/5783) I was just missing the [Brotli](https://pypi.org/project/Brotli/) package
After a `pip install Brotli` both prints worked fine

Comment: `response.encoding` in both cases is `utf-8` but the content received in the failing case is the raw Brotli-compressed data.

Comment: Per the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49584929/235698), `pip install brotli` then `brotli.decompress(response_br.content)`.