# Python requests.get gives response in different encoding

Tags: python, html, encoding

Following codes gives different results each time, sometimes in correct human readable ASCII, but other times in some other non-ASCII encoding format.

```
HEADERS = ({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7'})

page = requests.get('https://www.powerball.com/', headers=HEADERS)
print(page.text)
print(page.encoding)
```

The encoding of the page is always utf-8. What could be the reason for the difference?

Tried copy http headers from the request sent from browser but getting the same result.

Comment: Yep, that does, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `page.headers` dictionary contains `'Content-Encoding': 'br'`.  This indicates [Brotli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brotli) compression and is not supported by default from `requests` (as of version 2.31.0 anyway).

Per the [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/community/faq/) documentation:

> When either the [brotli](https://pypi.org/project/Brotli/) or [brotlicffi](https://pypi.org/project/brotlicffi/) package is installed, requests also decodes Brotli-encoded responses.

```py
# Note: pip install brotli
import requests
import brotli

HEADERS = ({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip'})

page = requests.get('https://www.powerball.com/', headers=HEADERS)
print(page.text)
```

Comment: Awesome, that works. Just using the ```pip install brotli``` works 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49584929/unable-to-decode-python-web-request