JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
I am trying to parse the content of an API response, which is of the type application/json. However, I am getting the following error:

JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

The API response data I wish to parse is in the following format:
{
    "articles": [],
    "news": [
        {
            "id": 123456,
            "url": "some-url",
            "description": "some-description"
        },
        {
            "id": 123456,
            "url": "some-url",
            "description": "some-description"
        }
    ],
    "blogs": [
        {
            "id": 123456,
            "url": "some-url",
            "description": "some-description"
        },
        {
            "id": 123456,
            "url": "some-url",
            "description": "some-description"
        },
        {
            "id": 123456,
            "url": "some-url",
            "description": "some-description"
        }
    ],
    "books": [],
    "events": [],
    "@pages": 0
}

My code is:
import requests

responseObj = requests.get(myAPIurl)
data = responseObj.json()

I would like to fetch the id for each category
Here is the complete error message:
{
    "name": "JSONDecodeError",
    "message": "Extra data: line 1 column 2 (char 1)",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/models.py:971, in Response.json(self, **kwargs)
    970 try:
--> 971     return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    972 except JSONDecodeError as e:
    973     # Catch JSON-related errors and raise as requests.JSONDecodeError
    974     # This aliases json.JSONDecodeError and simplejson.JSONDecodeError

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/json/__init__.py:346, in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    343 if (cls is None and object_hook is None and
    344         parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    345         parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 346     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    347 if cls is None:

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py:340, in JSONDecoder.decode(self, s, _w)
    339 if end != len(s):
--> 340     raise JSONDecodeError(\"Extra data\", s, end)
    341 return obj

JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 3
      1 #get the id of the Stock based on it's NSE symbol from Investing
      2 responseObj = requests.get(investing_url,headers=investing_headers)
----> 3 data = responseObj.json()

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/models.py:975, in Response.json(self, **kwargs)
    971     return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    972 except JSONDecodeError as e:
    973     # Catch JSON-related errors and raise as requests.JSONDecodeError
    974     # This aliases json.JSONDecodeError and simplejson.JSONDecodeError
--> 975     raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)

JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 2 (char 1)"
}


Can you edit the full error message into your question, please?

Is this the all response? this json is valid.

@Chris - I just updated the error message

@maverick-murthy, I suspect that the response isn't what you think it is. It looks like you're in a notebook environment? What value does responseObj.text have?

@Chris - this is a truncated value but it is showing something like this -
1x �M����m��8�WzՂN�     a�����x}��{�ǵ��V��Ma������(����(�f.5����?�b��1�_                                                                       

That's clearly not the same thing you showed above. Why do you expect the API response to resemble what you show in your question? If the endpoint is returning something that isn't JSON (a binary file, perhaps?) you won't be able to parse it using the json module.

The Content-Type header of the response shows application/json

Does the Content-Encoding header say it's gzipped or similar…?

@deceze - the Content-Encoding says br

See https://stackoverflow.com/q/49584929/476.

Thank you @deceze, that solved the problem.
